Recursive CTE in SQL Server
I have a table that looks like the following, only in reality, it has a lot more rows, the pattern persists.



start_eomonth_timestamp
end_eomonth_timestamp




2024-09-01
2024-10-01


2024-09-01
2024-11-01


2024-09-01
2024-12-01


2024-09-01
2025-01-01


2024-09-01
2025-02-01


2024-09-01
2025-03-01


2024-09-01
2025-04-01


2024-09-01
2025-05-01


2024-09-01
2025-06-01


2024-09-01
2025-07-01


2024-09-01
2025-08-01


2024-09-01
2025-09-01



What I am trying to do is perform a receivables run out on all the accounts. I need to do this for each start and end pair. The query I have is pretty long, in that it takes the start date as a snapshot start and the end is where I grab the comparison and make some calculations like so:
-- These dates will eventually be set dynamically
DECLARE @start_date DATE;
DECLARE @end_date DATE;

SET @start_date = '2022-09-01';
SET @end_date = '2022-10-01';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #c_comp_ar_tbl;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #start_tbl;

SELECT 
    Active_Archive,
    Hosp_Svc,
    Payer_organization,
    product_class,
    Pt_No,
    Unit_No,
    Unit_Date,
    Admit_Date,
    Dsch_Date,
    [start_date] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, EOMONTH_Timestamp),
    [start_fc] = FC,
    [start_ar_balance] = ISNULL(Balance, 0),
    [start_tot_chgs] = ISNULL(Tot_Chgs, 0),
    [start_tot_pay] = ISNULL(Tot_Pay_Amt, 0),
    [start_sys_allowance_amt] = ISNULL(SysAlw_Amt, 0)
INTO
    #start_tbl
FROM
    backup_tbl
WHERE 
    EOMonth_Timestamp = @start_date
    AND FC NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%';

SELECT 
    snap.Active_Archive,
    snap.Hosp_Svc,
    snap.Payer_organization,
    snap.product_class,
    snap.Pt_No,
    snap.Unit_no,
    snap.Unit_Date,
    snap.Admit_Date,
    snap.Dsch_Date,
    snap.start_date,
    snap.start_fc,
    [end_fc] = comp.fc,
    snap.start_ar_balance,
    [end_ar_balance] = comp.Balance,
    snap.start_tot_chgs,
    [end_tot_chgs] = comp.Tot_Chgs,
    snap.start_tot_pay,
    [end_tot_pay] = ISNULL(comp.Tot_Pay_Amt, 0),
    [start_sys_allowance_amt] = ISNULL(snap.start_sys_allowance_amt, 0),
    [end_sys_allowance_amt] = ISNULL(comp.SysAlw_Amt, 0),
    [change_in_ar_balance] = ISNULL(snap.start_ar_balance, 0) - ISNULL(comp.Balance, 0),
    [change_in_tot_chgs]  = ISNULL(snap.start_tot_chgs, 0) - ISNULL(comp.tot_chgs, 0),
    [change_in_tot_pay] = ISNULL(snap.start_tot_pay, 0) - ISNULL(comp.Tot_Pay_Amt, 0),
    [change_in_sys_allowance_amt] = ISNULL(snap.start_sys_allowance_amt, 0) - ISNULL(comp.SysAlw_Amt, 0)
INTO
    #c_comp_ar_tbl
FROM
    #start_tbl AS snap
LEFT JOIN 
    backup_tbl AS comp ON snap.Pt_No = comp.pt_no
                       AND ISNULL(SNAP.UNIT_DATE, '') = ISNULL(COMP.Unit_Date, '')
                       AND comp.EOMonth_Timestamp = @end_date

I'm not sure how to do this part iteratively/recursively. Ultimately I want all records UNION ALL so I am thinking recursive CTE. Just not sure on how to go about it. The dates would end up coming from the date table you see above as a table called #runout_dates_tbl.
Here is some dummy data
> dplyr::tibble(
+   active_archive = rep(c("active", "archive"), each = 5),
+   hosp_svc = rep(c("hosp1", "hosp2", "hosp3", "hosp4", "hosp5"), 2),
+   payer_organization = rep(c("payer1", "payer2", "payer3", "payer4", "payer5"), 2),
+   product_class = rep(c("class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5"), 2),
+   pt_no = 1:10,
+   unit_no = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
+   unit_date = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06")),
+   admit_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-10")),
+   dsch_date = as.Date(c("2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-09", "2019-01-10", "2019-01-11")),
+   start_date = rep(as.Date("2019-01-01"), 10),
+   start_fc = rep(c("fc1", "fc2", "fc3", "fc4", "fc5"), 2),
+   start_tot_charges = round(runif(10, min = 50000, 100000), 2),
+   start_sys_allowances = round(runif(10, min = 1000, max = 5000), 2),
+   start_tot_pay = start_tot_charges - (start_tot_charges - start_sys_allowances - round(runif(10, min = 1000, max = 5000), 2)),
+   start_ar_balance = start_tot_charges - start_tot_pay - start_sys_allowances
+ ) |>
+   knitr::kable()


|active_archive |hosp_svc |payer_organization |product_class | pt_no| unit_no|unit_date  |admit_date |dsch_date  |start_date |start_fc | start_tot_charges| start_sys_allowances| start_tot_pay| start_ar_balance|
|:--------------|:--------|:------------------|:-------------|-----:|-------:|:----------|:----------|:----------|:----------|:--------|-----------------:|--------------------:|-------------:|----------------:|
|active         |hosp1    |payer1             |class1        |     1|      NA|NA         |2019-01-01 |2019-01-02 |2019-01-01 |fc1      |          82924.07|              1152.29|       2328.33|         79443.45|
|active         |hosp2    |payer2             |class2        |     2|      NA|NA         |2019-01-02 |2019-01-03 |2019-01-01 |fc2      |          98892.31|              3584.77|       5357.43|         89950.11|
|active         |hosp3    |payer3             |class3        |     3|      NA|NA         |2019-01-03 |2019-01-04 |2019-01-01 |fc3      |          63651.41|              1269.31|       3891.28|         58490.82|
|active         |hosp4    |payer4             |class4        |     4|      NA|NA         |2019-01-04 |2019-01-05 |2019-01-01 |fc4      |          96180.85|              3731.53|       5251.96|         87197.36|
|active         |hosp5    |payer5             |class5        |     5|       1|2019-01-01 |2019-01-05 |2019-01-06 |2019-01-01 |fc5      |          89903.75|              1303.90|       6114.04|         82485.81|
|archive        |hosp1    |payer1             |class1        |     6|       2|2019-01-02 |2019-01-06 |2019-01-07 |2019-01-01 |fc1      |          97057.37|              2519.02|       4384.50|         90153.85|
|archive        |hosp2    |payer2             |class2        |     7|       3|2019-01-03 |2019-01-07 |2019-01-08 |2019-01-01 |fc2      |          95950.99|              1990.37|       3045.38|         90915.24|
|archive        |hosp3    |payer3             |class3        |     8|       4|2019-01-04 |2019-01-08 |2019-01-09 |2019-01-01 |fc3      |          72514.21|              3357.29|       7632.32|         61524.60|
|archive        |hosp4    |payer4             |class4        |     9|       5|2019-01-05 |2019-01-09 |2019-01-10 |2019-01-01 |fc4      |          50304.10|              1336.12|       2879.46|         46088.52|
|archive        |hosp5    |payer5             |class5        |    10|       6|2019-01-06 |2019-01-10 |2019-01-11 |2019-01-01 |fc5      |          72897.84|              3595.14|       8592.78|         60709.92|


It would help if we had some example records for the table  backup_tbl

I can try and dummy some up

fwiw, for historical reasons in SQL Server date value literals, with no time component, should use yyyyMMdd rather than yyyy-MM-dd like you see elsewhere.
